# How to check the versions of Sharepoint Server, services and patches of my Office 365 portal?

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, administration, office-365, office-integration

I am reading a lot that Office 365 has been patched, upgraded and now migrated to Server 2012 (and Office 2013).

How can I determine the versions of Sharepoint Server, services, etc. on which my Office 365 (Sharepoint Online) site(s) are run?
and of operating system?

I tried to search but all methods I could find require server/farm administration access to Sharepoint Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, self-trying to self-answer my own question, it seems impossible in development environment.

One of the workaround (from private communication by [Hilary Stoupa](http://www.infopathdev.com/members/Hilary-Stoupa.aspx)) is to configure public access through internet to an Office365 (Sharepoint online) site and in http://network-tools.com select http headers and type your Sharepoint site below then hit go. This, could probably sometimes show the version of Sharepoint, at least ...